# Gaussian Curvature for an isothermal parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry

In Do Carmo's "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces", in section 4-3 exercise 2 is the following:

> Show that if x is an isothermal parametrization, that is, $E=G=\lambda(u,v)$, and $F=0$, then $K= -\frac{1}{2\lambda}\Delta(log \lambda)$.

I have been trying to prove this for some time now and I am not sure if I am maybe missing an important lemma or theorem, since the other exercises were quite straightforward thus far. I have both tried to express $K$ as the product of principal curvatures as well as the determinant of $dN_p$, but neither approach led anywhere.

[Here is a link to the book, in case any of you need it.](http://www2.ing.unipi.it/griff/files/dC.pdf)

Comment: The book should have a formula for $K$ in terms of $E,F,G$ only. It’s known as Gauss’s Theorem Egregium.

Comment: Look at (and do?) Exercise 1 in section 4-3 (at least in the edition I have).

Comment: In general, exercises often build on earlier — maybe even immediately preceding — exercises.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now. I was trying to avoid having to understand christoffel symbols(I need the exercise for the proof of the local Gauss-Bonnet Theorem and was a bit afraid of having to endlessly backtrack through the entire book). Luckily the chapter was relatively self-contained.